# Diazo add unwanted html header into json response

Tags: plone, diazo

I have a blank Plone 4.1 site with only collective.quickupload installed. The upload portlet worked fine until I install plone.app.theming and apply my theme. The files were still uploaded, but the web client got "Failed" status.

Inspecting the ajax response from server I found that they were wrapped by html header.
The old response (before install diazo & apply my theme) was simply

```
{"success":true}
```

The new response (after install diazo and apply my theme) was being wrapped by a html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><p>{"success":true}</p></body></html>
```

I've pasted my rule.xml file here (nothing special, there is only one rule conditioned by css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper"): http://pastebin.com/SaK13Fni

What should I do to work around this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid this behavior you have to add an exception in  your `rules.xml` that specify to not apply your theme to your specific view , like this:

```
<notheme if-path="myjson_view"/>
```

**edit**:

I've tried with one of my diazo themes and a json view and I didn't have your issue. So I think the problem is either in your rules.xml or in your json view. You should try one of these two way:

1. change your `rules.xml` this way:

   ```
      <rules
       xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
       xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css"
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

       <!-- Prevent theme usage in zmi-->
       <rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">
           <theme href="index.html" />
       </rules>
   ```
2. have you already specified the "Content-type" of the output in
   your json view? Like this:

   ```
   self.request.response.setHeader("Content-type","application/json")
   return json_data
   ```

   If not, that's probably the problem.

Comment: Too bad it not worked. I've tried both add <notheme> inside root rules with css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper" or outside (wrap with another rules tag). I think the problem is the header is added before all the transformation to make sure it follows xhtml syntax.

Comment: I see. I've tried to reproduce your error and i've edited my answer consequently

Comment: Answer 2 here is correct. The next release of plone.app.theming will never theme ZMI pages.

Comment: Thanks guys,
The problem was that the content-type was set to text/html, that make the whole wrap thing expected/good behaviour.
A side note (Not related to the problem): Setting content-type back to application/json (or text/plain, text/json, whatever/whatever) make the html version of multiupload portlet collective.quickupload do not work on IE. I fell back to the flash version.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for using Chrome inspector... it adds the html head and pre tags around your json when you inspect it...it's not actually there if you look at view:source of the page (old school)...